# For i.i.d. $\{X_n\}$ proving $\frac1n\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|X_k|\xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}}0\Leftrightarrow E(|X_1|)<+∞$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Given that $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ are i.i.d., prove that$$
> \frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k| \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} 0 \Longleftrightarrow E(|X_1|) < +\infty.
> $$

*My try:*

Because $\varliminf\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \max\limits_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k|$ and $\varlimsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \max\limits_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k|$ are both measurable with respect to the exchangeable σ-algebra of $X_1, X_2, \cdots$, they are both almost surely constants by the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law, i.e.$$
\varliminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k| = c_1, \quad \text{a.s.} \tag{1}\\
\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k| = c_2, \quad \text{a.s.}
$$
where $c_1, c_2 \in [0, +\infty]$. Also, if the distribution function of $|X_1|$ is $F(x)$, then the distribution function of $\dfrac{1}{n} \max\limits_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k|$ is$$
F_n(x) = P\left( \frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k| \leqslant x \right) = \prod_{k = 1}^n P(|x_k| \leqslant nx) = (F(nx))^n,
$$
which implies\begin{align*}
E\left( \frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} |X_k| \right) &= \int_0^{+\infty} x \,\d((F(nx))^n) = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{+\infty} y \,\d((F(y))^n)\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{+\infty} y·n (F(y))^{n - 1} \,\d F(y) = \int_0^{+\infty} y (F(y))^{n - 1} \,\d F(y)\\
&\leqslant \int_0^{+\infty} y \,\d F(y) = E(|X_1|).
\end{align*}
Also for any $c > 0$,$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty P(|X_1| \geqslant ck) < \infty \Longleftrightarrow E(|X_1|) < +\infty. \tag{2}
$$
However, I failed to connect (1) and (2) to prove the proposition.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To downvoters: why not spend some time reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) and improve your own posts instead of casting malicious down votes here?

Comment: Would you consider adding me as a room owner in CURED? It's been at least six months since a mod from another site deleted me as a room owner. Just think about it.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not so informed about everything that has happened, so it seems imprudent for me to act unilaterally. Maybe you could ask in CURED for at least one more person's support, and I'll act then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $$\frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |X_k(\omega)| \to 0 \tag{3}$$ if, and only if, $$\forall \epsilon>0 \, \, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \, \, \forall n \geq N: \quad |X_n(\omega)| \leq n \epsilon. \tag{4}$$
2. Use the Borel cantelli lemma to show that $(4)$ (and hence $(3)$) holds almost surely if, and only if, $$\forall \epsilon>0: \quad \sum_{n \geq 1} \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq n \epsilon)}_{\mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq n \epsilon)} < \infty.$$
3. Combine Step 2 with $(2)$ to prove the assertion.

**Remark:** Step 1 is actually a purely deterministic result. For any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of real numbers the following equivalence holds: $$\frac{a_n}n \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0 \iff \frac1n\max_{k \leq n} |a_k|  \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$$