# Maximum of a sequence of iid random variables divided by n converges to 0 in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that if
$$
\{X_n, n \geqslant 1\}
$$
is a sequence of iid random variables with finite mean $ E[X] < \infty $
then $ \frac{\max_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} |X_i|}{n} \overset{P}{\to} 0 $.
I know I can convert a probability dealing with the maximum into a product of probabilities of individual $X_i$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I've got
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P( \frac{\max_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} |X_i|}{n} > \epsilon) = 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} P( \frac{|X_i|}{n} \leqslant \epsilon)^{n} = 0
$$

I think I need to use the fact that the expectation of $X$ is bounded; I'm not really sure how though.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2709011/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E|Y| <\infty$ implies that $\sum P(|Y| >n) <\infty$. Applying this to $Y=\frac {X_1} {\epsilon}$ we see that $\sum P(|X_i| >n \epsilon ) <
\infty$. Hence $P(\frac {\max \{X_k,X_{k+1},...,X_n\}} n >\epsilon) \leq \sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} P(|X_i| >n \epsilon )\leq  \sum\limits_{i=k}^{\infty} P(|X_1| >n \epsilon )\to 0$ as $ k \to \infty$. Can you finish the proof?

Here is a stronger result:

Let $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$. Then  $\frac {S_n} n \to EX_1$ with probability $1$ by Strong Law of Large Numbers. Now $\frac {X_n} n=\frac {S_n} n-\frac {n-1} n\frac {S_{n-1}} {n-1}$. Hence $\frac {X_n} n \to EX_1-EX_1=0$ with probability $1$. Thus $\frac {|X_n|} n \to 0$ with probability $1$. It is an elementary fact that if $a_n /n \to $ then $\max \{a_i: 1\leq i\leq n\} /n \to0$. We have proved a stronger result that $\max \{|X_i|: 1 \leq i\leq n\} /n \to 0$ with probability $1$

Comment: I like the proof of the stronger result but I have a few questions about the first proof.
Why can we say that $P(\frac{\max_{i \leq i \leq n} |X|}{n} > \epsilon) \leq \sum_{i = k}^{n} P(|X_i| > n \epsilon) $, i.e. why are we bounding the probability of the maximum of those rvs with a sum (not a product) of the individual random variables?

Comment: Let $A_i=( |X_i| >n\epsilon)$. Then $max_{k \leq i \leq n} |X_i| >n\epsilon$ iff $|X_i| >n\epsilon$ for some $i$ between $k$ and  $n$ so $\{max_{k \leq i \leq n} |X_i| >n\epsilon\} \subseteq \bigcup_{k \leq i \leq n} A_i$. Probability of a finite union is less than or equal to the sum of the probabilities. @user1845455

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove the strong convergence is by Borel Cantelli I.

Let's $Y_n$ the non negative rv.

$$\sum_n \mathbb{P}[\frac{Y_n}{n} >\epsilon]=\sum_n \mathbb{P}[Y_1 >n \epsilon]=\sum_n\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{(X_1 > n\epsilon)}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_n\mathbb{1}_{(n < \frac{X_1}{\epsilon})}]=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{X_1}{\epsilon}\rfloor}}]\leq \mathbb{E}[\frac{X_1}{\epsilon}]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_1]}{\epsilon}< \infty$$

As the series converges, it's a sufficient condition for strong convergence