# Prove that $\frac{\xi}{n} \to 0$ , where $\xi = \max(f_1 \dots f_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider $\xi = \max(f_1 \dots f_n)$ , where $f_i$ are i.r.v. with $\operatorname{E}(f_i) \ < +\infty$ and $f_i \stackrel{d}{=} f_j$.

We want to determine $\dfrac{\xi}{n} \to 0$ a.s.

I thought about continuous mapping theorems for $\bar{f_i} = \dfrac{f_i}{n}$. $\bar{f}_i \to 0$ and hence $\max(\bar{f_1} \dots \bar{f_n}) \to 0$.

But I guess this idea is quite incorrect. Any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For i.i.d. $\{X_n\}$ proving $\frac1n\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|X_k|\xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}}0\Leftrightarrow E(|X_1|)<+∞$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709011)